# Habilitar as cidades na edição do cadastro

Tags: jquery

Colegas.

Futucando daqui e dali, cheguei ao código abaixo. O objetivo dele é ao selecionar o estado, aparecer as cidades referentes aquele estado. Até aqui tudo certo, porém preciso fazer com que ao editar, as cidades apareçam e claro, a cidade cadastrada fique selecionada. O código é esse:

Ao popular o combox dos estados que vem do banco e selecionar o estado desejado, tenho o seguinte código:

```
$(function() {
    $("#estados").change(function() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "exibe-cidades.php?id=" + id,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(res) {
                $("#cidades").children(".cidades").remove();
                $("#cidades").append(res);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

O Combox está dentro de um método PHP dessa forma:

```
public function listarCidades($id){

      $sql = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT cod_estados, sigla FROM crm_estados ORDER BY sigla");
      $mostrar = "<select name=\"Estados\" class=\"select1_single form-control\" id=\"estados\">";
      $mostrar .= "<option value=''></option>";      

      while($listar = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
            $selected = ($id == $listar['cod_estados'])?("selected"):(null);
        $mostrar .= "<option value=".$listar['cod_estados']."  ".$selected.">".$listar['sigla']."</option>";
      }
       $mostrar .= "</select>";
       return $mostrar;
  }
```

Não acredito que a solução esteja no arquivo exibe-cidades.php, mas nesse trecho. Alguém teria alguma ideia?

O combox das cidades segue abaixo:

```
<option value="1" class="cidades">ACRELÂNDIA</option>
<option value="2" class="cidades">ASSIS BRASIL</option>
<option value="3" class="cidades">BRASILÉIA</option>
<option value="4" class="cidades">BUJARI</option>
<option value="11059" class="cidades">CAMPINAS</option>
<option value="5" class="cidades">CAPIXABA</option>
<option value="6" class="cidades">CRUZEIRO DO SUL</option>
<option value="7" class="cidades">EPITACIOLÂNDIA</option>
<option value="8" class="cidades">FEIJÓ</option>
<option value="9" class="cidades">JORDÃO</option>
<option value="10" class="cidades">MÂNCIO LIMA</option>
<option value="11" class="cidades">MANOEL URBANO</option>
<option value="12" class="cidades">MARECHAL THAUMATURGO</option>
<option value="13" class="cidades">PLÁCIDO DE CASTRO</option>
<option value="14" class="cidades">PORTO ACRE</option>
<option value="15" class="cidades">PORTO WALTER</option>
<option value="16" class="cidades">RIO BRANCO</option>
<option value="17" class="cidades">RODRIGUES ALVES</option>
<option value="18" class="cidades">SANTA ROSA</option>
<option value="19" class="cidades">SENA MADUREIRA</option>
<option value="20" class="cidades">SENADOR GUIOMARD</option>
<option value="21" class="cidades">TARAUACÁ</option>
<option value="22" class="cidades">XAPURI</option>
<option value="191" class="cidades">ALVARÃES</option>
<option value="192" class="cidades">AMATARI</option>
<option value="193" class="cidades">AMATURÁ</option>
<option value="194" class="cidades">ANAMÃ</option>
<option value="195" class="cidades">ANORI</option>
<option value="196" class="cidades">APUÍ</option>
<option value="197" class="cidades">ARIAÚ</option>
<option value="198" class="cidades">ATALAIA DO NORTE</option>
<option value="199" class="cidades">AUGUSTO MONTENEGRO</option>
<option value="200" class="cidades">AUTAZES</option>
<option value="201" class="cidades">AXINIM</option>
<option value="202" class="cidades">BADAJÓS</option>
<option value="203" class="cidades">BALBINA</option>
<option value="204" class="cidades">BARCELOS</option>
<option value="205" class="cidades">BARREIRINHA</option>
<option value="206" class="cidades">BENJAMIN CONSTANT</option>
<option value="207" class="cidades">BERURI</option>
<option value="208" class="cidades">BOA VISTA DO RAMOS</option>
<option value="209" class="cidades">BOCA DO ACRE</option>
<option value="210" class="cidades">BORBA</option>
<option value="211" class="cidades">CAAPIRANGA</option>
<option value="10471" class="cidades">CACAU PIRÊRA</option>
<option value="212" class="cidades">CAMETÁ</option>
<option value="213" class="cidades">CANUMÃ</option>
<option value="214" class="cidades">CANUTAMA</option>
<option value="215" class="cidades">CARAUARI</option>
<option value="216" class="cidades">CAREIRO</option>
<option value="217" class="cidades">CAREIRO DA VÁRZEA</option>
<option value="218" class="cidades">CARVOEIRO</option>
<option value="219" class="cidades">COARI</option>
<option value="220" class="cidades">CODAJÁS</option>
<option value="221" class="cidades">CUCUÍ</option>
<option value="222" class="cidades">EIRUNEPÉ</option>
<option value="223" class="cidades">ENVIRA</option>
<option value="224" class="cidades">FLORIANO PEIXOTO</option>
<option value="225" class="cidades">FONTE BOA</option>
<option value="226" class="cidades">FREGUESIA DO ANDIRÁ</option>
<option value="227" class="cidades">GUAJARÁ</option>
<option value="228" class="cidades">HUMAITÁ</option>
<option value="229" class="cidades">IAUARETÊ</option>
<option value="230" class="cidades">IÇANÃ</option>
<option value="231" class="cidades">IPIXUNA</option>
<option value="232" class="cidades">IRANDUBA</option>
<option value="233" class="cidades">ITACOATIARA</option>
<option value="234" class="cidades">ITAMARATI</option>
<option value="235" class="cidades">ITAPIRANGA</option>
<option value="236" class="cidades">JAPURÁ</option>
<option value="237" class="cidades">JURUÁ</option>
<option value="238" class="cidades">JUTAÍ</option>
<option value="239" class="cidades">LÁBREA</option>
<option value="240" class="cidades">LAGO PRETO</option>
<option value="241" class="cidades">MANACAPURU</option>
<option value="242" class="cidades">MANAQUIRI</option>
<option value="243" class="cidades">MANAUS</option>
<option value="244" class="cidades">MANICORÉ</option>
<option value="245" class="cidades">MARAÃ</option>
<option value="246" class="cidades">MASSAUARI</option>
<option value="247" class="cidades">MAUÉS</option>
<option value="248" class="cidades">MOCAMBO</option>
<option value="249" class="cidades">MOURA</option>
<option value="250" class="cidades">MURUTINGA</option>
<option value="251" class="cidades">NHAMUNDÁ</option>
<option value="252" class="cidades">NOVA OLINDA DO NORTE</option>
<option value="253" class="cidades">NOVO AIRÃO</option>
<option value="254" class="cidades">NOVO ARIPUANÃ</option>
<option value="255" class="cidades">OSÓRIO DA FONSECA</option>
<option value="256" class="cidades">PARINTINS</option>
<option value="257" class="cidades">PAUINI</option>
<option value="258" class="cidades">PEDRAS</option>
<option value="259" class="cidades">PRESIDENTE FIGUEIREDO</option>
<option value="260" class="cidades">REPARTIMENTO</option>
<option value="261" class="cidades">RIO PRETO DA EVA</option>
<option value="262" class="cidades">SANTA ISABEL DO RIO NEGRO</option>
<option value="263" class="cidades">SANTA RITA</option>
<option value="264" class="cidades">SANTO ANTÔNIO DO IÇÁ</option>
<option value="265" class="cidades">SÃO FELIPE</option>
<option value="266" class="cidades">SÃO GABRIEL DA CACHOEIRA</option>
<option value="267" class="cidades">SÃO PAULO DE OLIVENÇA</option>
<option value="268" class="cidades">SÃO SEBASTIÃO DO UATUMÃ</option>
<option value="269" class="cidades">SILVES</option>
<option value="270" class="cidades">TABATINGA</option>
<option value="271" class="cidades">TAPAUÁ</option>
<option value="272" class="cidades">TEFÉ</option>
<option value="273" class="cidades">TONANTINS</option>
<option value="274" class="cidades">UARINI</option>
<option value="275" class="cidades">URUCARÁ</option>
<option value="276" class="cidades">URUCURITUBA</option>
<option value="277" class="cidades">VILA PITINGA</option>
```

Comment: Podes mostrar o HTML e explicar o que vem na string do ajax?

Comment: Perdoe-me Sérgio. O HTML seria o que exatamente? Posso colocar o PHP que traz o select (HTML), pois ele está dentro de um método. Seria isso?

Comment: Sim pode ser o php, melhor ainda seria a string que retorna o ajax. Tipo `console.log(res);` dentro desse `success: function(res) {`. Mas também o HTML de `#cidades`

Comment: Certo. Vou editar meu post e colocar o PHP lá...

Comment: Não sei se seria exatamente isso, veja: Calling Element.createShadowRoot() for an element which already hosts a shadow root is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4668884095336448 for more details.
VM12894:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null(anonymous function) @ VM12894:5(anonymous function) @ VM12894:20
editar-escolas.php?key=1679091…:431  e o outro combox

Comment: _"e o outro combox"_ - é isso que era interessante ver. Que presumo estar na consola depois de teres feito `console.log(res);`

Comment: Certo. Editei meu post... pois ficou muito extenso para colocar aqui

Comment: Como estás a ir buscar o `$id` que passas á função no PHP?

Comment: O problema está aí.... quando vou editar, o campo das cidades fica desabilitado e só é habilitado quando seleciono um estado. Precisaria que ele ficasse desabilitado e com a cidade selecionada sem ter que selecionar um estado primeiro...

Comment: Mas no php tens `public function listarCidades($id){` e imagino que seja o `id` que vem do Ajax. Como estás a receber esse valor no PHP e a chamar essa função?

Comment: Na verdade esse id vem do link editar-dados.php?key=(id que vem do banco de dados) e na página de edição, pego com o $_REQUEST. O link que exibe as cidades é exibe-cidades.php?id=+id; que está dentro do jquery

Comment: É a linha onde fazer algo como `$id = $_REQUEST['id'];` e depois como tratas essa variável até chamares a função que é interessante para a pergunta...

Comment: Chamo dessa forma: include("classes/metodosClass.php"); $metodos = new metodosClass(); $metodos->listarCidades($id);

Comment: E usas `$id = $_REQUEST['id'];` assim? sem mais nada?

Comment: isso... pego e jogo dentro do método, pois ele vem de uma query string

Comment: Ok, agora há ainda mais perguntas antes de perceber a tua lógica completa :) Dentro da função `listarCidades` estás a gerar este HTML: `<select name=\"Estados\" class=\"select1_si ... etc`. Isso é para os estados... certo? E de onde vem o HTML que a consola mostrou? `<option value="1" class="cidades">ACRELÂNDIA</option>
etc...`?

Comment: Após chamar a função, em outra div coloco a chamada das cidades dessa forma:  <span class="carregando">Aguarde, carregando...</span>
                        <select name="Cidades" class="select2_single form-control" id="cidades">     
          </select> e mais abaixo o jquery do post $("#estados").change(function() {.....